# How to make sure that a field in SQL query is unique?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, join

I have the following query

```
 SELECT nature_images.image_code, 
           nature_objects.name 
    FROM nature_images 
    LEFT JOIN nature_objects 
         ON nature_images.object_id = nature_objects.id 
         AND nature_images.approved = 1 
    ORDER BY RAND() 
    LIMIT 0,5
```

The result is returning repeated nature_object.ids but with different nature_objects.id, what I basically need is that the nature_object.id is unique in every row returned and doesn't get repeated.
I tried using SELECT DISTINCT but that seems to fail.. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: exactly how are you producing this `object 2`? That's not something mysql would spit out, unless you were storing that exact text inside the db somehow.

Comment: @MarcB No, I'm not storing it that way or SQL is returning it that way, I'm just explaining the nature of the result, that this query might return two different nature images for the same object which I do not want.

Comment: use group by and get max code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do a `GROUP BY` on object name and get maximum code or minimum code.

```
SELECT MAX(nature_images.image_code), 
       nature_objects.name 
FROM nature_images 
LEFT JOIN nature_objects 
     ON nature_images.object_id = nature_objects.id 
     AND nature_images.approved = 1 
GROUP BY nature_objects.name
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 0,5
```